# python search for a value in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Python - regarding dictionaries, I currently have an empty (well, almost empty - with one dummy element) array of dictionary items, with a "name" and a freq

```
[{"name": "XYZ","freq": 1}]
```

I am running a process wherein : 
- I will obtain a new "name" value
- If this does not already exist in the dictionary, I append the same
- If this does exist, I increment the frequency by 1 (freq +=1)

The following is my code, at first I thought it worked well, then I realised that there does not seem to be any "incrementing" that occurs (freq is always one) - can someone help me understand what to change?

Thanks in advance !
Sundar

```
#Dummy array
CompName=[{"name":"","freq":0}]
for file in os.listdir(frame_loc):
#generate name from some process and add the same
    name={"name":CompNameText,"freq":1}
    gen=(CompNameText for name in CompName if CompNameText in name.values())
    if CompNameText in gen:
        name["freq"]=name["freq"]+1
    else:
 #I feel it always executes only the else part of the condition, not the if
        CompName.append({"name":CompNameText,"freq":1})
```

Comment: The `name` dict is re-initialized to `{"name":CompNameText,"freq":1}` every iteration. This should be moved to above the loop.

Comment: thanks, @RafaelC - I feel that *if* executes only if CompName already contains the name (the dictionary element name - sorry for the confusing terms) - therefore if I append it again, wont that be a repeated entry rather than an update?

Comment: Thanks, @DeepSpace - every iteration deals with a different file, therefore I do not want my existing "name" dict to spillover, hence re-initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is fine, but there is a builtin data structure that is perfect for this task called `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
namecounts = defaultdict(int)
print(namecounts)
namecounts["Fred"]+=1
print(namecounts)
```

You supply `defaultdict` a callable, and whenever you search for a key in the dict that is not found, that function is called and set as the corresponding value to the key you looked for. In the above example, you looked for "Fred", which was not found, and therefore `int` was called with zero arguments returning the identity value of int (zero), which is then incremented to 1 and stored as the value to the key "Fred".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all that answered - Zoe's answer helped me frame the below logic - I believe the difference was adding (.values()) to refer the value . 
It is not exactly a straightforward if-else - I will have to write another condition to evaluate once the entire thing runs. However, it will do for now.

I do wish that I can do away with the abc = 0 though, removing it throws up an error.

```
CompName=[{"name":"AB","freq":1},
   {"name":"BC","freq":1},
   {"name":"CD","freq":1}]
CompNameText="XY"
abc=0
for AllNames in CompName.values():
    if CompNameText in AllNames["name"]:
        print("Found")
        AllNames['freq']=AllNames['freq']+1
        break
else:
    abc+=1

if abc == len(CompName):
    CompName.append({"name":CompNameText,"freq":1})


print(CompName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a better layout for dictionary searching:

```
if specific_name not in dict:
    dict[specific_name]=0
dict[specific_name] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Zoe - however, I get another dict added to CompName - not a freq +=1 -- this does give me another idea, though, let me just try it and get back. Thanks